# If natural number $n$ doesn't has the form of $k^{m}$, for natural $k$ and $m$, then $x^{m}=n$ has no rational root.

Tags: proof-writing, roots

> Prove: If a natural number $n$ doesn't has the form of $k^{m}$, where $k$ and $m$ are natural numbers, then the equation $x^{m}=n$ has no rational root.

How do I start to prove with contradiction (or another method if it doesn't work)?

My first thought of this proof is [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). I know by substituting $n=k^{m}$ into the equation above implies $x=k$, which is also a natural number. However, this is not the proof that I wish to proceed, so anyone have some idea to start my proof?

Comment: Assume that $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. Proceed from there to show that $x$ must in fact belong to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Why avoid the natural  $1$-line RRT proof? Many other proofs will be equivalent to repeating RRT's proof in this special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\frac{p}{q}$, with $(p,q)=1$,  is a rational root of $x^m = n$ we conclude that

$\frac{p^m}{q^m} = n$ or equivalently $$n\cdot q^m = p^m\tag{1}$$

Now let $p_i$ be any prime divisor of $n$, say with multiplicity $k_i$. Then $p_i^{k_i}| n$ and  $n | n \cdot q^m = p^m$, so that $p_i | p$. If $l_i$ is the multiplicity of $p_i$ in $p$ then $m*l_i = k_i$ by the unique prime decomposition theorem, as $p_i$ does not divide $q$, so that $p_i$ fits exactly $k_i$ times in the left hand side of (1). This shows that each prime factor of $n$ occurs a multiple of $m$ times, which means that $n$ is an $m$-th power.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose there is a rational root - call it $\frac{p}{q}$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$

Plug that in the equation and see that it results in the equation:

$$p^m=nq^m$$

Now use the fact that $\gcd(p,q)=1$, by (for example) looking at a prime divisor of $q$ (if such exists)

Comment: To show the uniqueness of $p$ and $q$ using Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: To get a contradiction with the existence of the prime divisor of $q$, forcing it to be $1$

Comment: Let say $x^{m}=n$ has a rational root of $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p \geq 0$, $q>0$ and $GCD(p,q)=1$. Then plug it into the equation gives $p^{m}=nq^{m}$. Since $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers, then $p=kq$ for some rational number $k$. Raise power of both sides to m such that $p^{m}=k^{m}q^{m}$ and it shows $n=k^{m}$. I don't know if it is worked by making comparison.

Comment: I wonder if my method shown on above works?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to prove the contrapositive? Suppose that $\exists x\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x^m=n$. Since $n>0$, Assume that $x>0$ and $x=\frac{b}{a}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $a,b>0$, gcd$(a,b)=1$. Then $(\frac{b}{a})^m=n$ or $b^m=a^mn$.$\;$ Now consider prime factorizations of $a,b,n$ and recall the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: I just recall Euclid Lemma and has done my proof. Thanks.